# Configuring context-sensitive menu

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm using the vertex theme from https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats. However, I'm seeing several applications in the context-sensitive menu which I don't even have installed, and want to remove them. For example, AVAHI SSH Session, IntelliJ IDEA, and urxvt (tabbed). When I select any of these items nothing happens. If I install IntelliJ through my package manager (pacman on my arch system) then I get a second entry for IntelliJ and that one actually launches the program. Also it's annoying that Visual Studio Code is in the Accessories submenu. I want it in the Development submenu.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out by accident. I was just researching how to configure VLC media player skins, and on their website, they describe where to place the skins. Under $HOME/.local/share/applications I found a directory called jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop. I simply moved the "applications" folder to $HOME and restarted awesome wm. Now the old and icon-less IntelliJ entry in the context-sensitve menu is gone. Answering my own question for posterity in case someone finds it useful.